# Android development environment difficulties

Tags: java, android, eclipse

Lately I've been having problems developing Android applications. I'm in a Windows XP environment, using Eclipse 3.5 with the ADT tools.  The emulator takes a bit of time to load, but that's always been normal. What is not normal is that when I go to run my program in the emulator at least 50% of the time Eclipse cannot connect to the emulator and either I have to use adb kill-server && adb start-server or restart the emulator or restart eclipse.

This has been happening with so much frequency that it is becoming very problematic. Should I put a newer version of eclipse (3.7) to replace this one?  Any other things I can try?

Android development should be smoother as many people are developing Android apps these days.

Comment: You can refer [this][1] post. Enabling snapshot may help you a bit.


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator

Answer (score 1):

Try [Android x86](http://www.android-x86.org/). It works much more faster than Google Android emulator. Follow these steps:

1. Install [VirtualBox](http://www.virtualbox.org/).
2. Download [iso-file](http://code.google.com/p/android-x86/downloads/list) that you need
3. Create a virtual machine Linux 2.6/Other Linux, 512 Mb RAM, HD 2 Gb. Network: PCnet-Fast III, attached to NAT. You can also use bridged adapter, but you need a DHCP server in your environment.
4. Install Android x86 on the emulator, run it.
5. Press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, type `netcfg`, remember the IP, press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F7</kbd>.
6. Run cmd on your XP, change dir to your Android tools dir, type
   `adb connect <virtual_machine_IP>`
7. Start Eclipse, open ADT plugin, find the device, enjoy!

Source : [Why is the Android emulator so slow? How can we speed up the Android emulator?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1554099/slow-android-emulator)